# Upgrading to python3.6 from python2.7 in superset

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6, apache-superset

Just as the title said, is there an easy way to upgrade python version from 2.7 to 3.6 of superset and keep all old data and information (Dashboard,Charts,Tables)?

I use the old version of superset is 0.25.6 and python is 2.7 for now.

And I want to upgrade to 0.28 for superset, but the version 0.28 is not support python2.7.

I can not just use command to upgrade:

```
pip install superset -- upgrade
superset db upgrade
```

I found that if use command `pip install superset` would install at path `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and use command `pip3 install superset` would install on path `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`.

The old version of superset and data is at path python2.7, but the new one will build at path python3.6.

How can I move the old version of superset and data to new version?

Answer (score 1):

Superset stores all the data of dashboards, charts, tables and datasources in it's own db. Just setup a clean copy of superset which uses python3.6 by default and replace the working database with a copy of your old database.

Answer (score 0):

This worked on ubuntu 16.04

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.6 python3.6-dev
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python3.6 get-pip.py
pip3 install superset
```

Comment: Hi @akG, thanks for reply.
I have no question about from python2 to python3 but in superset upgrading.
I wanna move the old Dashboard,Charts,Tables to new superset version but face some trouble.

Comment: How do you install Database dependencies for SQL server with this python path ?